# Lost SSH Access to GCE Instance After Restoring Snapshot: Port 22 Connection Refused

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've encountered an issue while trying to restore a snapshot onto a Google Compute Engine (GCE) instance. It appears that I've completely lost SSH access to the machine. When I try to access it using a local shell, I receive the following error message: ssh: connect to host port 22: Connection refused. Moreover, when I try to access SSH through the Google Cloud browser interface, it also reports that port 22 is not opened.

I attempted several troubleshooting steps, including opening ports on the firewall and converting the snapshot into an image before attempting the restoration. None of these steps resolved the issue.

Does anyone have any recommendations to restore SSH access or advice on why this may have occurred during snapshot restoration? Any ideas or help are greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

I have attempted several potential solutions to regain SSH access to my Google Cloud Engine instance. After receiving the error message indicating that port 22 connection was refused, I first checked the firewall rules to ensure that port 22 was open for SSH traffic. I expected this solution might work as restricted ports are a common cause for such connection issues.
When this did not solve the issue, I converted the snapshot into an image and tried to restore the instance from this image, anticipating that this process could resolve any problems within the initial snapshot causing the SSH connection issue.
However, neither of these steps has solved the issue. I was expecting to regain SSH access to the GCE instance after these attempts, but the connection is still being refused on port 22. I am left perplexed as to why restoring a snapshot would cause a loss of SSH connectivity, and I'm unsure about the next best steps to resolve this issue.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console

Comment: You will need to know how to debug and read the logs of the OS firewall and OpenSSH server. There are good tutorials on those applications on the Internet.